# function addrow() in javascript something wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function addRow() {

    var medicinename = document.getElementById("medicinename");
    var time = document.getElementById("time");
    var duration = document.getElementById("duration");
    var when = document.getElementById("when");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= medicinename.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= time.value;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= duration.value;
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= when.value;

    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 =document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text"; 
    element2.setAttribute("name", "productDynamic");
    var get=medicinename.value;
    element2.value = get;
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
}
```

here i am going to insert value in table by using `onclick` function of javascript. I have 5 columns and in first column I am inserting delete button. Its all ok with it.but `var cel2=row.insertcell(1)` going wrong something it shows me 6 columns. I tried but i can not figure it out. Is there anybody in javascript can help me?one more thing is when i pass the value to table by textfield it is ok, but when i use select field by using option value it passed but value not catch by using like this `element2.setattribute("name","productDynamic");` what should i have to do for that also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

row.insertCell insert a new row with given index.

> If index is -1 or equal to the number of cells, the cell is appended
>   as the last cell in the row. If index is greater than the number of
>   cells, an IndexSizeError exception will result. If index is omitted it
>   defaults to -1. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

So I think if you create a new cell at an existing Index, it will be append. If you want to overwrite the cell, just get it with `row.cells[index]` an give it a new value.